# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows. Nested Tree Of Cases

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT [ReportId],
(SELECT CASE WHEN ReportId NOT IN 
(SELECT ReportId FROM [Tracker].[dbo].[Approvals] WHERE role = 2 and Status = 2) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM [Tracker].[dbo].[Approvals]) as isApprovedManager,
(SELECT CASE WHEN ReportId NOT IN 
(SELECT ReportId FROM [Tracker].[dbo].[Approvals] WHERE role = 3 and Status = 2 AND ReportId IN 
(SELECT ReportId FROM [Tracker].[dbo].[Approvals] WHERE Role = 2 and Status = 2)) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM [Tracker].[dbo].[Approvals]) as isApprovedAccountsPayable
  FROM [Tracker].[dbo].[Approvals]
  GROUP BY ReportId
```

Basically its a nested tree to find out where between roles 1-4 the current level is at. In order for 2 to be valid 1 also has to be approved and so forth. I have only written a section of the tree as it doesn't work so I have stopped until I fix this much. I am getting the error:

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Aprovals Table: 3 Columns all int, ReportId, Role, Status.

Sample Data: Input / Output

http://jsfiddle.net/J3V88/

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?  There are probably other ways to write this query.

Comment: Can you simplify further to find out which subquery is returning more than 1 value?

Comment: The First NOT IN is returning more than one @automatic

Comment: Here I made a sample table @Gordon Linoff http://jsfiddle.net/J3V88/

Comment: "NOT IN (x)" is allowed to use `x` with more than one row. The problem is that he's outputting subqueries as columns, and one of *those* subqueries are returning more than one 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be the use of the full table in the select without filtering for the current expensereportid. The case statements may be directly run instead of using select again. Please see if this works for you:

```
SELECT distinct
  [ExpenseReportId], 
  CASE 
     WHEN ExpenseReportId NOT IN 
           (SELECT ExpenseReportId FROM [ExpenseTracker].[dbo].[Approvals] 
            WHERE role = 2 and Status = 2) 
     THEN 0 
     ELSE 1 
  END as isApprovedManager,
  CASE 
     WHEN ExpenseReportId NOT IN 
           (SELECT ExpenseReportId 
            FROM [ExpenseTracker].[dbo].[Approvals] 
            WHERE 
               role = 3 and Status = 2 
               AND ExpenseReportId IN 
                  (SELECT ExpenseReportId FROM [ExpenseTracker].[dbo].[Approvals] 
                   WHERE Role = 2 and Status = 2)) 
     THEN 0 
     ELSE 1 
  END as isApprovedAccountsPayable
FROM 
  [ExpenseTracker].[dbo].[Approvals]
--GROUP BY ExpenseReportId
```

Comment: Thanks, according to my test data this came up with the correct results :D I owe you big time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.[ReportId],
CASE WHEN B.[ReportId] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END isApprovedManager,
CASE WHEN C.[ReportId] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END isApprovedAccountsPayable
from [Tracker].[dbo].[Approvals] A
left outer join 
(
  SELECT ReportId 
  FROM [Tracker].[dbo].[Approvals] 
  WHERE role = 2 and Status = 2
) B ON A.[ReportId] = B.[ReportId]

left outer join 
(
  SELECT ReportId 
  FROM [Tracker].[dbo].[Approvals] 
  WHERE role = 3 and Status = 2 
  AND ReportId IN
    (
      SELECT ReportId 
      FROM [Tracker].[dbo].[Approvals] 
      WHERE role = 2 and Status = 2
    )
) C ON A.[ReportId] = C.[ReportId]
```

Comment: I have Incorrect Syntax at IS and also THEN in the first section with CASE

Comment: can you post full error? Make sure all column names match your original column names from the tables.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.